# Query Store on Amazon RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, query-store

I'm trying to use Query Store on SQL Server on Amazon RDS, and not having any luck. The query store works for a few hours after each failover, but then stops working. For example, our last manual failover was June 13 @ 5am. When I query the records in the query store, the last record there is from June 13 @ 10am. When I try to clear the query store, the records aren't removed. Same happens if I try to turn query store off for the databases.

```
SELECT  RecordCount = COUNT(*), 
        LastDate = MAX(last_execution_time)
FROM    sys.query_store_runtime_stats;
GO
ALTER DATABASE [foo] SET QUERY_STORE CLEAR;
GO
SELECT  RecordCount = COUNT(*), 
        LastDate = MAX(last_execution_time)
FROM    sys.query_store_runtime_stats;
```

... returns ...

```
RecordCount LastDate
----------- ----------------------------------
9025        2017-06-13 10:13:16.0500000 +00:00

(1 row(s) affected)

RecordCount LastDate
----------- ----------------------------------
9025        2017-06-13 10:13:16.0500000 +00:00

(1 row(s) affected)
```

I'm hoping that I'm just missing an RDS specific method for dealing with the query store, but have found nothing of use yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the result set of this query?
SELECT actual_state, actual_state_desc, readonly_reason,   
    current_storage_size_mb, max_storage_size_mb  
FROM sys.database_query_store_options;

Comment: 2, READ_WRITE, 0, 31, 150

Comment: Also worth noting, SQL version is 13.0.4422 - 2016 Standard SP1 + CU2

Comment: and now you are not able to clear the content of the Query Store?

Comment: correct - using the sa account, when I run alter database set query_store clear, nothing happens. Query store records are all still there, and I get no error saying that it didn't work.

Comment: I can't reproduce it on my machine. Though I don't have CU2 for SP1.

Comment: @ScottIvey - I realize this question is 6 years old but did you ever find a solution? I am running into the same problem.

Comment: @Igor - I did not.